# Is there electric field inside the conductor in moving charges case?

Tags: electric-circuits, electric-fields, electricity, charge, electric-current

Is there an electric field inside a conductor when steady current passes through it ?

I have two conflicting notions here : I was watching this [Electroboom video](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=O-WCZ8PkrK0&t)  and at minute $14:00$ electroboom starts explaining about the surface charges and movement of charges. There is no form of opposing electric field to cancel out our own electric field , hence I decided that it should not be $0$ because its the driving factor of movement of electrons.[image]

Second is this stack exchange [answer](https://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/175468/is-there-no-electric-field-inside-a-conductor): Which clearly suggests that there is no electric field in an ideal conductor , since there is no need of electric field to drive the current (only accelerate it ).

Both of these are equally contradicting in my opinion and hence I have two questions :

1)If the electric field really cancels out in the ideal steady current case , then how does the new electrons from the negative terminal get accelerated to receive a direction to flow ,  after the field and current are set up it hints that the electrons must somehow accelerate without a net force (electric field).

2)If answer two is correct then what might be the opposition factor in the electroboom video

Comment: One source is about a conductor with resistance and the other source is about a conductor with no resistance.